# AndroidStudio compiling native code shows "fcntl(): Bad file descriptor"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have a legacy app that a fellow developer was seeing `fcntl(): Bad file descriptor` when building our native cpp code within AndroidStudio.

Our build environment supports building from the command line (for scripting and doing daily automatic builds) using locally installed NDK as well as through AndroidStudio. We set `local.properties` to point to the locally installed NDK.

I could not determine the cause of the `fcntl` error and **was not seeing it myself when running NDK r17. I then updated to NDK r21d (June 2020) and immediately see the same thing** within AndroidStudio.

```
fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : vhc_jnilib <= Png.cc
fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : vhc_jnilib <= Jpeg.cc
fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : vhc_jnilib <= MyContainer.cc
fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : vhc_jnilib <= aIdentityInfo.cc
fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : vhc_jnilib <= UpdateImage.cc
fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
```

Android Studio 4.0, MacOS Catalina 10.15.4, Gradle 6

Questions:

- Any idea how I can get more information on what tool is generating this warning?
- What does this imply and can it be silenced or fixed?

Comment: See related discussion here:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-27776

Comment: Any update on  this? please let me know..

Comment: @DeepDave no, updated to latest AndroidStudio 4.0.1 and now building for API 30 and still see the same thing.

Comment: @spartygw I removed NDK Code.
I will use cmake next time if needed

Comment: The bug mentioned by Anton, says it was fixed in June 2020. `Closing ticket, Fix verified SDK version 9.0.3.v20200609060523 and SDK version 9.1.0.v20200609061322` but I still get the error today. @spartygw have you found a solution to this? Thanks

Comment: @Houman5 Nope. Still streaming fcntl errors.

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: @EduardoFernandes nope :(

Comment: @Rob you are right, updated.

Answer (score 9):

**The project path cannot have spaces.**

I have encountered the same problem, when I removed the spaces in the project path, the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks, not applicable to me. No spaces in my project paths.

Comment: Make sure to check your drive name, mine had a space in its name. Removed it and all works now!

Comment: How is this still a problem in 2021!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I'm not sure what was the actual cause of it, but I got it fixed by deleting `.gradle`, `.cxx` & `build` directories and then rebuilding the project.

Comment: No change for me. What version of AndriodStudio and NDK are you using?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 4.1, NDK version: r21d (21.3.6528147), Gradle version: 6.5, MacOS Catalina (10.15.7). Could you please try `invalidate caches/Restart` under `File` menu  & then `Refresh Linked C++ projects` under `Build` menu after deleting the above mentioned directories?

Comment: Just tried the invalidate and refresh but still see the `fcntl` error

Answer (score 0):

I have had this warning for some time, compiling the tess-two library. I have just upgraded my Android NDK version to the latest - 23.1.7779620 - and the warning has disappeared. I would therefore recommend that anyone with this problem should upgrade their NDK.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded make from 3.8x to 4.4x and this problem went away.